# Don't open Service Control Manager

Tags: c#, windows-services

I cann't open Service Control Manager(SCM) for creating service, function return to me 0:

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, ScManagerAccess dwDesiredAccess);

...
IntPtr scm = OpenScManager(ScManagerAccess.SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | ScManagerAccess.SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
...

private static IntPtr OpenScManager(ScManagerAccess rights)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(null, null, rights);
        if (scm == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to service control manager.");
        return scm;
    }

[Flags]
public enum ScManagerAccess
{
    SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x0001,
    SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002,
    SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x0004,
    SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x0008,
    SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x0010,
    SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x0020,
    SC_MANAGER_STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = (int)StandartAccess.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED,
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = (SC_MANAGER_STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
                             SC_MANAGER_CONNECT |
                             SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE |
                             SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE |
                             SC_MANAGER_LOCK |
                             SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS |
                             SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG)
}
```

But if I try use access only for connect, it return to me not 0.

Whats wrong? Maybe if I want to use the access creating I need some rights to start application?

Comment: What is the value of `GetLastError` after `OpenScManager` fails (try throwing a Win32Exception instead of ApplicationException; that should include the error code; or call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`)? Make sure you run your application as adminstrator, because it is very likely that `SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE` requires admin privileges. The error code of `GetLastError` should tell you.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks you for help. I checked it and got an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED(0x5)

Comment: That means you aren't running the application as administrator.